# My log4j log file is too large

Tags: jboss, log4j

A single log4j file (created anew each day) on my jBoss server consumes 22GB. This is too much. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Lower your logging level.  If its above `INFO`, that's too high except in debugging situations.
2. Look at what your application is logging.  If there is too much coming out of your application, maybe your logging from app code is too verbose.
3. If you have framework code, such as Hibernate, check to make sure its not logging unnecessarily. For instance, Hibernate can log all the SQL it spits out; that may be unnecessary for your needs.

This is really an environmental-specific question.  Take a look at how your server is configured, what your app is spitting out, and what frameworks are logging.  The culprit is there somewhere.

Comment: i view the log file,that s found Logging level is ERRO,and i found it has so many repeat contents while a erro accured